# Installing Ember.js 2.2

Tags: ember.js

I tried do install Ember.js v2.2 by following the official instructions: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/getting-started/

- installed Node.js and npm
- installed Git
- installed the Ember CLI via `npm install -g ember-cli`

Everything should be fine now.

But when I type `ember -v` to verify the Ember version, it says: 1.13.13
I did follow the 2.2 Instructions to the point, but I didn't get Ember.js 2.2 installed.

Any suggestions? I use Win 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ember` on the command line is actually invoking Ember-CLI, so `ember -v` will show you the version you have for Ember-CLI.  When you do `ember new <your project>` to create a project then you can manually change the Ember and Ember Data dependency versions in `bower.json` and `package.json`.  Make sure to update both files (for now at least) and rerun `npm install` and `bower install` in the project's root directory.

The Ember version set by default with ember-cli does not track the most recent version of Ember, but you can update to 2.x.  See the [changelog](http://ember-cli.com/#changelog).

Ember itself you will interact with in the browser after running `ember server` and going to your `localhost`.

Comment: Where do I find theses JSON files?

Inside an ember project folder? Or is there something like a global location where I can set the desired version for every (future) project?

Comment: Your answer should be given +1, but my reputation isn't high enough to do so. Nevertheless thank You very much for Your precise answer!

Answer (score 1):

For `ember 2.2` + `ember-data 2.3.1`:

```
ember new <project> && cd <project>
```

Edit `bower.json` in your project root directory (you're there already if you followed the previous command):

1. Replace `ember-cli-shims` version number to `0.1.0`
2. Replace `ember` version number to `2.2`
3. Remove the `ember-data` dependency line
4. Add the following code just above the last `}`

`,
  "resolutions": {
    "ember": "^2.2.0"
  }`

Edit `package.json` in your project root directory:

1. Replace `ember-data` version number to `2.3.1`

Clean the caches, update the project dependencies and then restart `ember`:

```
npm cache clean && bower cache clean && npm install && bower install
ember serve
```

And you're done. Open your browser console and you should see debug messages with the `2.2` version of `ember` and `2.3.1` version of `ember-data`.